# steam login page - displaying captcha in phantomjs

Tags: linux, windows, phantomjs, captcha, steam

I'm trying to log in into the site with the Steam account using PhantomJS and it was working all good until I did not upload script on the Linux VPS where PhantomJS is asking for a captcha to log in into the Steam. Why captcha is not displaying on my Windows computer? After removing cookies on my computer captcha is still not displayed.

[Windows result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxAUS.png)

[Linux result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egw1E.png)

Answer (score 0):

CAPTCHA is a reminder that you should not access a service via automated means like bots, so please, don't do it.

There is [an official Steam Web API](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API) in case you need to get some data from Steam.